# Subselecting matrix and use logical selection (matlab)

Tags: matlab, variables, selection, subset

I have a line of code in matlab for which i am selecting a subset of a matrix:

`A(3:5,1:3);`

Now i want to adapt this line, to only select rows for which all three values are larger than zero:

`(A(3:5,1:3) > 0);`

But apparently i am not doing this right. How do i select part of the matrix, and also make sure that only the rows (for which all three values are) larger than zero are selected?

---

EDIT: To clarify: lets say that i have a matrix of coordinates called A, that looks like this:

```
Matrix A [5,3]

3  4  0
0  1  0
0  3  1
0  0  0
4  8  7
```

Now i want to select only part [3:5,1:3], and of that part i only want to select row 3 and 5. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
A(find(sum(A(3:5,:),2)~=0),:)
```

will return only the rows of `A(3:5,:)` which have a row-sum not equal to zero.

If you had posted syntactically correct Matlab it would have been easier for me to cut and paste your test data into my Matlab session.

Comment: Thanks. And as for the syntax, i am an absolute beginner at matlab, so i'm continuously trying to make it as syntactically correct as possible. But i'm still not very good at it (i'm more used to java, and still trying to wrap my head around matlab's use of matrices and vectors). I could never have gotten to where i am now without SO, so i appreciate all the help. What part exactly wasn't syntactically correct?

Comment: Your matrix of integers should be something like [3 4 5;1 2 3] for easy cut and paste by SO.  What you've shown is the output form, what we need for our ease is the input form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm modelling this answer off of `A(find( A > 0 ))`

```
distances = pdist(find( pdist(medoidContainer(i,1:3)) > 0 ));
```

This will give you a vector of values in the `distances` variable.  The reason the `pdist(medoidContainer(i,1:3) > 0)` does not work is because it first, finds the indices specified by `i,1:3` in `medoidContainer`.  Then it finds the indices in `medoidContainer(i,1:3)` that are greater than 0.  However, since `medoidContainer(i,1:3)` and `pdist` now likely have different dimensions, the comparison does not give the right indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that was not completely what i was looking for. I rephrased my question (because it was a bit confusing), hope it is more clear now. Could you take a look at it and tell me what you think?